# Open ball in a normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Definition: A real normed vector space is a real vector space $E$ with a function $||$ such that, for any $x,y\in E, a\in \mathbb{R}$,
>
> N1) If $x\ne 0$, then $|x|>0$.
>
> N2) $|a\cdot x| = |a|\cdot|x|$
>
> N3) $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$

A real normed vector space can be a metric space with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

I know that in $(E,d)$ no point are isolated But given a open ball $B = B(a;r)$ in a real normed vector space $E$ and a point $b \in E$ with $|b-a| = r$, I'm struggling to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $x\in B$ such that $x\in B(b,\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the point $x = \frac{\varepsilon}{2r} a + \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2r}\right) b \in E$:

$x \in B(b, \varepsilon)$ since:
$$|x - b| = \left|\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2r} a + \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2r}\right) b\right) - b\right| = \frac{\varepsilon}{2r}|b - a| = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$$

Also, $x \in B(a, r)$ since:
$$|x - a| = \left|\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2r} a + \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2r}\right) b\right) - a\right| = \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2r}\right)|b - a| = r-\frac{\varepsilon}{2} < r$$

This assumes $\varepsilon < 2r$, otherwise you can always take $x = a$.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanodroid's construction looks a bit subtle, and I wanna give you an intuitive feeling.

In fact, what Mechanodroid did was to find a point closed to $b$ and lying on the line connecting $a$ and $b$. You can suppose this point, say $\lambda$, is $ta+(1-t)b$ and $t\in(0,1)$, and hence $\vert \lambda-b\vert = t\vert b-a\vert,$ and $\vert \lambda-a\vert = (1-t)\vert b-a\vert.$

You can see $$(1-t)\vert b-a\vert \lt \vert b-a\vert=r $$ always holds, which means that $\lambda$ always is in the ball $B(a,r)$, coinciding with our intuition.

You can choose $t$ small so that $t\vert b-a\vert \lt \epsilon$, and once t is determined, $\lambda$ is also determined.

And so we find such point as wish.